# How can i find how many sandbox connect with a production org?

Tags: apex

I want to know how many sandbox is connected with my org and what type of sandboxes they are??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Setup, enter Sandboxes in the Quick Find box, then select Sandboxes.
Sandboxes displays the available sandboxes that you purchased and a list of your sandboxes in use.

Comment: By code is it possible????

Comment: Yes you can use tooling api to do it. Below is a sample GET call in prod org- 
/services/data/v40.0/tooling/query?q=SELECT+SandboxName+FROM+SandboxInfo

Comment: "message" : "\nSELECT SandboxName FROM SandboxInfo\n                        ^\nERROR at Row:1:Column:25\nsObject type 'SandboxInfo' is not supported. If you are attempting to use a custom object, be sure to append the '__c' after the entity name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.",
  "errorCode" : "INVALID_TYPE"

Comment: This will work only in production not in sandbox. Check idea for this https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000lKVBQA2

Answer (score 1):

From your production organization, navigate to

> Setup > Deploy > Deployment Settings

This will show you all the sandboxes connected to your production organization along with the sandbox type and how it is connected to production.

To only know about the sandbox details and perform any actions(create/refresh/delete) on sandboxes, navigate to

> Setup > Deploy > Sandboxes

**Using Apex**

You will have to use API in order to get the sandboxes information, you can use below code to get the required information. This below code will give you sandbox names, if you need additional fields you can add to the query.

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint(Url.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()+'/services/data/v36.0/tooling/query/?q=select+id,sandboxname+from+sandboxinfo');
req.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer '+UserInfo.getSessionId());
req.setMethod('GET');
HttpResponse res = new http().send(req);
```

You will have to parse this response to get all the required information from it.

**Note : This won't work in sandboxes, it will work only in production environment.**

Comment: Can i find by apex code